# type "string" doesn't conform to protocol "sequence"

Tags: swift, string, sequence

Why does it come to this when I try to print every char in string a?

```
import Foundation


let a = "what is this"
for b in a {
    print(b)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `String` is not a sequence, you need to call the `characters` property to get a [`sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview).

```
let a = "what is this"
for b in a.characters {
  print(b, terminator: "")
}

// "what is this"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `characters` member variable of `String` if you want
to enumerate all the characters.

```
let a = "what is this"
for b in a.characters 
{
   print(b)
}
```